# UWP: Check, create and add data to file

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I created a Function to check if the file "test.txt" exists:

```
Public Function CheckIfFileExists(sFileName As String) As Integer

     Dim Location As Windows.Storage.StorageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
     Dim lstfiles = Location.GetFilesAsync(Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)
     Dim foundfiles = lstfiles.GetResults
     Dim bFound As Integer
     bFound = 0

     If foundfiles IsNot Nothing Then

         For Each sFile In foundfiles
             If sFile.Name = sFileName Then
                 bFound = 1
                 Exit For
             End If
        Next
     End If
     Return bFound

End Function
```

Now, when I first call CheckIfFileExists(FILENAME) in my main function, e.g.

```
CheckIfFileExists("test.txt")
```

, it returns an "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" saying that I'm calling the method at an unexpected time.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Is it related to the fact that I use asynchronous function in a synchronous function?

If yes, how do I have to modify my function to work asynchronuosly?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: modified question to meet requirements

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it related to the fact that I use asynchronous function in a synchronous function?

Yes, you should always await the asynchronous GetFilesAsync method:

```
Public Async Function CheckIfFileExists(sFileName As String) As Task(Of Integer)

    Dim Location As Windows.Storage.StorageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
    Dim lstfiles = Await Location.GetFilesAsync(Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)
    Dim foundfiles = lstfiles
    Dim bFound As Integer
    bFound = 0

    If foundfiles IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each sFile In foundfiles
            If sFile.Name = sFileName Then
                bFound = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return bFound
End Function
```

And the CheckIfFileExists method:

```
Dim b As Boolean = Await CheckIfFileExists("test.txt")
```

Comment: Using the function you described above throws the much-loved error: **....CheckIfFileExists(System.String)' has a parameter of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Int32>' in its signature. Although this generic type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, the type or its generic parameters implement interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types.  Consider changing the type 'Task' in the method signature to one of the following types instead: ....**

Comment: I did some research in the web and found out that I have wrap the function you suggested in a non-async function, described here:
[link](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/how-to-expose-async-methods-in-a-windows-runtime-component/). Additionally `CheckIfFileExists` has to be put as PRIVATE !!